# How to install java neural network framework in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java

Can anyone tell how to install a Java neural network framework in ubuntu 14.04?
After downloading the package I am unable to install it via the terminal.

Comment: A neural network is a conceptual idea, from the human brain... Which/what are you talking about? And will this be a programmer question  on a Linux question?

Comment: Which package did you try to install? Can you give us more details about the problems you got when installing it?

Answer (score 0):

With Neuroph, after downloading the zipped distro, unzip it, reference at least the core jar (neuroph-core-2.9.jar) and import the necessary classes in your java project. It can be downloaded from from http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/download.html with its NetBeans IDE as a separate download and the latter requires a window system for installation and use. Its API docs are at http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html.em.